# CKEditor 3.6.2 version issue in IE 10

Tags: xpages

CKEditor component doesn't work in Internet Explorer 10.

See http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9741

Does anyone have any advice how to do any workaround? Or do someone know when they will fix it?

Thanks in advance, JiKra

Comment: #TongueInCheek: Ditch IE10 .or. install ChromeFrame inside IE10. I suspect all JS developers are sick of hacking their code for the IE family

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, IBM Domino 9 and IBM XWork Server 9 use CKEditor 3.6.3 where this bug with IE10 is fixed.

For 8.5.3 I am using the following to make IE10 run as IE9 in order for the CKEditor to work:

```
<xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:
   if (context.getUserAgent().isIE()) {
     var response = facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
     // Use IE9 mode because of CKEditor bugs with IE10
     response.setHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=9");
   }
}]]></xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
```