# Richtext Field buttons not working in IE

Tags: xpages

It seems that the certain richtext button just does the field refresh and hence nothing gets changed. So, after selecting the text in the editor if we try to perform any of the below "yellow marked (in the image) " operation it just refreshes and nothing happens.

[image]

I am using domino 8.5.3 and I have tried IE 10, 13. Any suggestion, or should I just report it as a bug?

Public Link (for testing): http://teamground.de/test.nsf/home.xsp

Comment: Check the network tab or Console on developer tools. It may be throwing a client-side JavaScript error (i.e. a Dojo issue on the Console tab) or returning an error after a partial refresh (check the contents on the HTML on the network tab).

Comment: Yes, I did check the network and console tab. On page with Richtext  , onload it throws a NotSupportedError. However, this error is thrown onload and not on button click..on button click it just deselects the selected text without performing the given operation..Do you want me to share a public link?

Comment: It's probably not doing anything because there's a JavaScript error onload, so it can't load the module fully for the buttons to work

Comment: So, a bug to report? or any way around?

Comment: Check for compatibility issues between Internet Explorer 10 and the version of CKEditor used in Domino 8.5.3. If it's a bug, it sounds like a bug with CKEditor, not Domino. As far as I'm aware IBM have not modified the standard functionality in that area. (This assumes you're using the standard CKEditor rich text editor that comes with 8.5.3 and not explicitly telling it to use the Dojo editor)

Comment: possible duplicate of [CKEditor 3.6.2 version issue in IE 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202727/ckeditor-3-6-2-version-issue-in-ie-10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Domino 8.5.3 comes with CKEditor 3.2.1.6 http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/wpd_whatsnew.html?cp=SSVRGU_8.5.3%2F1. Searching the web I can see lots of issues of versions of CK Editor not working on Internet Explorer 10.

You may need to upgrade Domino to have a version of CKEditor that is supported by Internet Explorer 10. Domino 9.0 FP2 packages a version of CK Editor that supports Internet Explorer 11 http://per.lausten.dk/blog/2014/08/xpages-and-domino-9-0-1-fp2-upgrades-to-ckeditor-and-dojo.html

Comment: Looks like this question may be of relevance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202727/ckeditor-3-6-2-version-issue-in-ie-10

Comment: Alright, so, I did a small test on my side..As you mentioned Domino 9.0 works perfectly fine with IE 11...I also tried using the dojo module and a dojo editor but the problem persists..so the solution here is to upgrade domino for an updated CKEditor?right?

Comment: Also, I tried the suggestion mentioned on the link for 8.5.3 with no success..It still persists..

Comment: Just to clarify: 8.5.3 comes with CKEditor 3.5.3. It was 8.5.2 that came with 3.2.1.6.

Comment: Chintan, you are not setting X-UA-Compatible to IE9 in http://teamground.de/test.nsf/home.xsp. So please try again.

Comment: That was a public link, I did try it on my local server..but I guess I could be wrong..Let me verify it and update the status tomorrow..! Thanks a lot :)..Its really good to see replies from some of the masters in this field..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Paul Withers and Per Henrik Lausten. It is partially a duplicate question as marked here. 
The solution mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202727/ckeditor-3-6-2-version-issue-in-ie-10) is precisely for IE 10.
However, I faced a problem because of the IE version. I thought I will just document it for others. IE 11.0.9 responds "unknown" and hence it doesn't change the response header. I designed a small function for later versions of IE. Hopefully this could help anyone:

```
 function isIE() {
      var isBrowserIE = false;
      if (context.getUserAgent().getBrowser() == 'Unknown') {
          var userAgent = context.getUserAgent().getUserAgent();
            if (userAgent.indexOf('Trident/7') > -1 && userAgent.indexOf('rv:11') > -1) {
                isBrowserIE = true;
            }
      }
      if (context.getUserAgent().getBrowser() == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
          isBrowserIE = true;
      }
      if (context.getUserAgent().getBrowser() == 'IE') {
          isBrowserIE = true;
      }
       return isBrowserIE;
    }
```

And then as suggested by Per Henrik Lausten we could render the response header to IE 9 (would just copy it for one click answer)

```
<xp:this.beforeRenderResponse><![CDATA[#{javascript:
   if (isIE()) {
     var response = facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
     // Use IE9 mode because of CKEditor bugs with IE10
     response.setHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=9");
   }
}]]></xp:this.beforeRenderResponse>
```